# Different design for two calendars on the same page

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, datepicker

I am trying to make two calendars in the same .html file but with different design. Specifically, I need to have different colors of the .ui-widget-content (top of the calendar).

I tried to add and id to each of the inputs and then css them but it is not working. Perhaps I have to add id or class to datepicker elements in some other way than just writing it inline? So how can I style two JQuery UI calendars differently on the same page?

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script> 
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="/resources/demos/style.css">
  <script>
 $(document).ready(function(){
  $( "#datepicker" ).datepicker();
  $( "#datepicker2" ).datepicker();
 });  
  </script>
  
  <style>
 #datepicker .ui-widget-content {
  color: pink;
 }
 #datepicker2 .ui-widget-content {
  color: green;
 }
 </style>
</head>
<body>
 
<p>Date: <input type="text" id="datepicker"></p>
<p>Date2: <input type="text" id="datepicker2"></p>

</body>
</html>
```

CSS is working when I add it simply with no subclasess or sub id's but when I try to specify it for each of the calendars design does not change.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add a class to particular datepicker then using that class you can override it check snippet.

**Add class using**

I added a class `aa`

```
$("#datepicker2").datepicker({
        beforeShow: function(input, inst) {
          $(inst.dpDiv).addClass('aa');
        }
      });
```

**Override Css**

```
.aa a.ui-state-default {
  background: green;
}
```

```css
.aa a.ui-state-default {
  background: green;
}
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>

<head>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="/resources/demos/style.css">
  <script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
      $("#datepicker").datepicker({
        beforeShow: function(input, inst) {
          $(inst.dpDiv).removeClass('aa');
        }
      });
      $("#datepicker2").datepicker({
        beforeShow: function(input, inst) {
          $(inst.dpDiv).addClass('aa');
        }
      });
    });
  </script>

  <style>
    #datepicker .ui-widget-content {
      color: pink;
    }
    
    #datepicker2 .ui-widget-content {
      color: green;
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body>

  <p>Date: <input type="text" id="datepicker"></p>
  <p>Date2: <input type="text" id="datepicker2"></p>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: It worked! Also for my desired result alphaColor css should look like this: 
.alphaColor .ui-widget-header {
  color: pink;}

Comment: Thank you so much I was searching for 5 hours for this :/

Comment: StackOverflow is game changer so whenever you stuck ask you will get solution soon.

Answer (score 2):

The issue is that the datepicker Dom elements are not children of your input. But added to the dom directly. Simply add a class on initialisation

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script> 
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="/resources/demos/style.css">
  <script>
 $(document).ready(function(){
  $( "#datepicker" ).datepicker({
      beforeShow: function(input, inst) {
         $('#ui-datepicker-div').removeClass('betaColor').addClass('alphaColor');
         }
      });
  $( "#datepicker2" ).datepicker({
    beforeShow: function(input, inst) {
       $('#ui-datepicker-div').removeClass('alphaColor').addClass('betaColor');
       }
   });
 });  
  </script>
  
  <style>
 .alphaColor {
  color: pink;
 }
 .betaColor {
  color: green;
 }
 </style>
</head>
<body>
 
<p>Date: <input type="text" id="datepicker"></p>
<p>Date2: <input type="text" id="datepicker2"></p>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thank you! This also works well (as well as the first answer)

Answer (score 1):

Or you can try this:

If you want add css argument you can use:

```
 <script>
  $(document).ready(function(){
  $("input#datepicker").focus(function() { 
            $("#ui-datepicker-div").css("background", "red"); 
        }); 
  });  
  </script>
  <script>
  $(document).ready(function(){
  $("input#datepicker2").focus(function() { 
            $("#ui-datepicker-div").css("background", "purple"); 
        }); 
  });  
  </script>
```

or you can use addclass jquery method and add styles to your css file.

```
 <script>
  $(document).ready(function(){
  $("input#datepicker").focus(function() { 
            $("#ui-datepicker-div").addClass("dpicker1"); 
        }); 
  });  
  </script>
  <script>
  $(document).ready(function(){
  $("input#datepicker2").focus(function() { 
            $("#ui-datepicker-div").addClass("dpicker2");
        }); 
  });  
  </script>
```

and add style code to your css file like as:

```
.dpicker1 {background:red}
.dpicker2 {background:purple}
```

eg: https://jsfiddle.net/4obL2v15/